The word "kallah" in the Song of Solomon

"I have come to my garden, my sister, my spouse (kallah)" (Song of Solomon 5:1)

What is the reason that the word is "kallah" (bride) instead of "kallati" (my bride)? Other such words are used with the pronoun "i" (my): "akhoti" (my sister), "yonati" (my dove), "rayati" (my love) etc. Also, wouldn't "ha-kallah" be more accurate grammatically since it is a talking a specific bride

Many assume this is simply a copyist's omission.

Why would he omit it in all places where this word is used? One omission could be a mistake but all of them are intentional

The 34 occurrences of the noun כַּלָּה (Kallah) show an interesting pattern in the OT:

24 times it means "daughter-in-law", eg, Gen 11:31, 38:11, 16, 24, Lev 18:15, 20:21, Ruth 1:6, 7, 8, 22, 2;20, 22, 4:15, 1 Sam 4:19, 1 Chron 2:4.
10 times it means "bride", eg, SS 4:8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 5:1, Isa 49:18, 61:10, 62:5, Jer 2:32.

In the six instances in the Song of Solomon we have the following grammatical constructions, all of which appear to be used in what we would now call the vocative case; however, Hebrew does not have a vocative case and the nominative is used to denote the vocative.  Specifically (my translation),

SS 4:8 - Come with me O bride ...
SS 4:9 - You have ravished my heart, my sister, O bride ...
SS 4:10 - How beautiful is your love, my sister, O bride ...
SS 4:11 - Your lips drip as the honeycomb, O bride ...
SS 4:12 - A garden enclosed is my sister, O bride ...
SS 5:1 - I have come into my garden my sister, O bride ...

Technically, when the construction, "my sister O bride" occurs, it should be seen as a noun chain and so should be translated, "my sister of bride" but this means that the possessive "my" applies to both and so can be legitimately rendered, "my sister my bride" when in a construct chain.  However, I prefer the vocative rendering.
